# lookup external list

Tags: lookup-column, external-list

I have two tables:

1. Documents
2. Project task

What I am looking for is the following:

- I have a page with project tasks in a hierarchy list (done)
- Clicking on a task will open an edit screen (done)
- In this screen, I want a list with all documents belonging to this task
- The documents table is not deployed on the same site (look-up columns seem to require this)

How can I create a list in the edit page with all documents, belonging to the task? Is this possible with look-up columns or is there another way to achieve this?

Thank you for your time

Comment: could you say more about your SP environment (2007/2010, Foundation/Ent Server, etc) ?

Comment: Sorry. Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 with the following services: - Business Data Connectivity Service 
          - Central Administration 
          - Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Database 
          - Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Database 
          - Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail 
          - Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application 
          - Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service

Answer (score 1):

Did  you try to use Sparqube Lookup? It supports to lookup documents from another site or even cross  site collection. http://www.sparqube.com/SharePoint-Lookup-Column/.